# Export data as XSV from oracle

Tags: oracle, csv, export, sqlplus

I want to export some data (i.e. some queries results') from an old oracle database into a file, values separated with a specified character or sequence of characters. A CSV file is an example.

Only integers, varchars (without newline included), dates, other basic values (?) into result set, so no LOBs or another fancy stuff. Just plain data, NO PADDING, NO WRAPPING, fields separated and maybe enclosed.

Practicaly, I'm looking for a simple "SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE FIELDS TERMINATED BY ... [OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char'" from mysql, but for Oracle.

I tried to use sqlplus, but any program should be ok, as long as it runs on linux console and it's not java based :-P.

Unfortunately I cannot use "SET SQLFORMAT csv", seems to be not supported.

So far I've got best results with something like:

printf "set echo off newpage 0 pagesize 0 arraysize 5000 feed off head off trimspool on trimout on\nselect field1 || '|' || field2 from table;" | sqlplus -S database > output_file

Set arraysize 5000 (maximum) gives the best performance, unfortunately wraps the result if lines are longer than 80 chars.

Set linesize 30000 (or even 32767) cancels wrapping, unfortunately the performance becomes horrible. I don't want to specify a maximum linesize for each query (calculating maximum size for each field in result), hoping that performance will rise.

After reading tons of answers I'm still not getting close to a solution that should be both CORRECT and PERFORMANT. My next call will be writing a php file to do the job, but it's a nonsense, IMHO using the default application sqlplus should give the best performances ...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for everyone that had this problem, here is the answer:

Make sure you have at least oracle client 12.2 installed.
If not, you can extract the files from instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip (library files) and from jar archives from sqlplus related directories from linuxx64_12201_client.zip (client/stage/Components/oracle.sqlplus*). Those two zips are available to download for free (registration required) at oracle download site. I didn't want to install that version of the client because it could mixed up with local installed one. It's kind of an ugly hack, but at least no file on system was modified.

From 12.2 onwards the "set markup csv" command is supported, and the command was:
printf "set head off\nset feedback off\nset arraysize 5000\nselect field1, field2 from table;" | LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/oracle12/lib ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/oracle12 /path/to/oracle12/bin/sqlplus -M "CSV ON" -S database

adjust the arraysize variable (5000 is maximum and fastest, but pay attention to the memory), choose the "SET MARKUP CSV {ON|OFF} [DELIMI[TER] character] [QUOTE {ON|OFF}]" parameters and enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell whether this set of `SET` commands will help (I use it, usually), but - try it.

```
set termout off 
set trimspool on 
set echo off 
set verify off 
set autoprint off 
set serveroutput off 
set arraysize 1000 
set pagesize 0
set linesize 100
set long 10000
set numwidth 10
set feedback off
set colsep ';'

col empno format 99999
col ename format a10
col sal format 999G990

spool emp.txt
select empno, ename, sal from emp;
spool off
```

At the bottom, you can see some `COL` formattings; remove it if you don't need it.

Don't set linesize to that high number (30.000) if you don't really need it.

Also, there's the `set colsep ';'` which will separate columns by that separator (semi-colon in this example; can be any other character, such as `|` you mentioned).

In order to speed up spool:

- set termout off
- set trimspool on
- run it on **server**, not on the client PC

Comment: thanks but unfortunately none of the options you provide made any change; the numbers are still right aligned (which I can avoid by concatenating to an empty string); also the output is spooled to the specified by but also on the console; and no change in performance time

Comment: what I do not understand is who is doing the formatting ? is it the server (and the transfer is text only, which could explain the lack of performance when increasing the linesize parameter), or the sqlplus client, so the transfer between client and server is binary as it should ?

Comment: also running sqlplus on the server may indeed improve the performance, unfortunately it's not an option